# Script to open a URL in chrome browser in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to write a script to run in rails console so that whenever I hit a URL, instead of giving the result as response, I want something to be triggered so that the URL is opened in chrome browser.

Example:

```
def open_url_in_chrome_browser(url)

end
```

When the function is called, the URL should open in chrome.

Comment: Got the answer to it:

Used the gem 'Launchy'

require 'launchy'

Launchy.open("http://www.voonik.com/admin/orders/R540610117-1/download_invoice.pdf")

This will open the URI in the default browser

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using this command on ubuntu machine.

```
exec("google-chrome www.google.com")
```

you can also define a method like for your local machine like this

```
def open_url_in_chrome_browser(url)
  exec("google-chrome www.google.com")
end
```

Comment: I am using Mac OS and the above command does not seem to work.
Throwing an error : -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"google-chrome www.google.com"'